# Python 3 Recursive LinkedList Node Insertion

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to create a recursive function to insert into a linked list at a certain position to solve a [hackerrank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/problem), as part of educating myself in python. However, (according to hackerrank) it seems to be incorrect. Could someone help explain where I might be going wrong?

```
"""
 Insert Node at a specific position in a linked list
 head input could be None as well for empty list
 Node is defined as

 class Node(object):

   def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
       self.data = data
       self.next = next_node

 return back the head of the linked list in the below method. 
"""

def InsertNth(head, data, position):

    # if we've found our position, then insert Node with pointer to next/None
    if head == None or position == 0 :
        return Node(data, head)

    # if we're at the next to last position, then update it's pointer to our new Node
    elif position == 1  :
        head.next = Node(data, head.next)

    # otherwise, step position down, and perform recursion
    else :
        InsertNth(head.next, data, position-1)
```

I've put in comments to try to explain what I'm understanding to be my logic so if anything's not clear, please let me know.

Comment: The assignment says _"return back the head of the linked list"_. Now look closely at your code and see if it does that... I don't get the feeling that you've tried very hard to debug your code. (That's just one of the mistakes though)

Comment: @Aran-Fey It was a little difficult to debug through the hackerrank website, and yes, I seem to have overthought this. I've added an acceptable (by hackerrank standards) answer. However, I'd still like to ask that if the requirement was purely just inserting a node at a particular position, would my original code be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Posted a solution that was found acceptable by hackerrank:

```
def InsertNth(head, data, position):
    # if we have found our position, then create a new Node 
    if head == None or position == 0 :
        return Node(data, head)
    else :
        next_node = head
        while position > 1 :
            next_node = next_node.next
            position -= 1

        next_node.next = Node(data, next_node.next)

    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of it. Hope it helps. Feel free to ask questions if there's anything you're unsure about.

```
def InsertNth(head: Optional[Node], position: int, data: Optional[Node]) -> Optional[Node]:
    """Returns a new list where the second list is spliced into, or inserted at, given an index."""
    if (position > 0):
        if (head is not None):
            return Node(head.data, splice(head.next, position - 1, data))
        else:
            if (data is not None):
                if (data.next is not None):
                    return Node(data.data, splice(head, position, data.next))
                else:
                    return Node(data.data, head)
            else:
                return None
    else:
        # If position <= 0, splice data list at start of head list
        # This is the same process whether the position < 0 from the start or becomes < 0.
        if (data is not None):
            if (data.next is not None):
                return Node(data.data, splice(head, position - 1, data.next))
            else:
                return Node(data.data, head)
        else:
            if (head is not None):
                return head
            else:
                return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for recursive solution. Here is my implementation which got accepted.

```
def insertNodeAtPosition(llist, data, position):
    # Write your code here
    if(llist==None or position<0):
        return llist

    if(position==0):
        node = SinglyLinkedListNode(data)
        node.next = llist
        return node

    llist.next = insertNodeAtPosition(llist.next,data,position-1)   
    return llist
```